# C# Running MDX queries via ADOMD asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, mdx, adomd.net

I have a series of mdx queries to run (18 in total) and each query can take between a few seconds and 8 minutes to run depending on the cube caching etc.

Following code works to run an MDX query

```cs
 public DataTable GetMDXData(string server, string database, string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var connString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Catalog={1}", server, database);

        //Create Query
        using (AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = connString;

            using (AdomdCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            using (AdomdDataAdapter da = new AdomdDataAdapter())
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    //Execute Query
                    conn.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm looking at running this asynchronously, but the `AdomdDataAdapter` does not currently seem to have a `FillAsync` method like the `SqlDataAdapter`.

I've tried converting the method to be `async Task<DataTable>` and replaced the da.Fill(dt); with `await Task.Run(() => da.Fill(dt));` but I'm then getting a locking issue.

I'm still trying to get my head around async and I've previously only consumed Async methods with async/await. My understanding is Task.Run starts a new thread which is why I'm getting this issue? What's the best approach here?